# NatTable - CheckBoxCellEditor & CheckBoxPainter displaying the text on single click

Tags: java, eclipse, checkbox, swt, nattable

I am using CheckBoxCellEditor and CheckBoxPainter to display Boolean attribute inside the NatTable as shown below

[image]

**Problem : On single click of cell using mouse, it displays boolean value as text as shown below, instead of resetting the state to false.**

[image]

Below is my code snippet,

```
//register the column
ColumnOverrideLabelAccumulator columnLabelAccumulator = new ColumnOverrideLabelAccumulator(
                bodyLayer.getBodyDataLayer());
        bodyLayer.getBodyDataLayer().setConfigLabelAccumulator(columnLabelAccumulator);
        columnLabelAccumulator.registerColumnOverrides(0, COLUMN_BOOKMARK_LABEL);

//added the CheckBoxCellEditor and CheckBoxCellPainter to configuration.
     natTable.addConfiguration(new AbstractRegistryConfiguration() {
                    @Override
                    public void configureRegistry(IConfigRegistry configRegistry) {
                        configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(EditConfigAttributes.CELL_EDITOR, new CheckBoxCellEditor(), DisplayMode.NORMAL,
                                COLUMN_BOOKMARK_LABEL);

                        configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(CellConfigAttributes.CELL_PAINTER, new CheckBoxPainter(ImageUtil.getImage("Images.BookmarkChecked"),
                                ImageUtil.getImage("Images.BookmarkUnchecked")),
                                DisplayMode.NORMAL, COLUMN_BOOKMARK_LABEL);

                        configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(CellConfigAttributes.DISPLAY_CONVERTER,
                                new DefaultBooleanDisplayConverter(), DisplayMode.NORMAL, COLUMN_BOOKMARK_LABEL);
                    }
                });
```

I also, have rowselectionProvider to set the default selection to first row and also to refresh the properties UI based on the row selection.

Any pointers on what is the missing link.TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a painter registered for `DisplayMode.SELECT` which is taken instead of the painter that is registered for your label in `DisplayMode.NORMAL`. Adding this line should solve your issue

```
configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(
    CellConfigAttributes.CELL_PAINTER, 
    new CheckBoxPainter(
        ImageUtil.getImage("Images.BookmarkChecked"),
        ImageUtil.getImage("Images.BookmarkUnchecked")),
    DisplayMode.SELECT, 
    COLUMN_BOOKMARK_LABEL);
```

I'm not sure about the rest of your style configuration. Typically the configurations are hierarchical. So it needs to be checked in detail why another painter is used than the one for the NORMAL mode.

Comment: Many thanks for quick reply. You are right, I had custom HeaderStyleConfiguration which was overriding the CheckBoxPainter mode. I reordered the configuration and now, I can see the Images with checked and unchecked status.

Comment: Now Mouse Event listener is not triggering for selection.                                   addConfiguration( new AbstractUiBindingConfiguration()
    { public void configureUiBindings( UiBindingRegistry uiBindingRegistry iBindingRegistry.registerFirstDoubleClickBinding( new CellEditorMouseEventMatcher( GridRegion.BODY ),
            new MouseEditAction() );}

Comment: Could you then please accept the answer? So users with similar issues find the solution easier.

Comment: Do you use a custom edit binding configuration? Then you need to ensure that the CheckboxPainter is configured correctly.

uiBindingRegistry.registerFirstSingleClickBinding(
                new CellPainterMouseEventMatcher(GridRegion.BODY, MouseEventMatcher.LEFT_BUTTON, CheckBoxPainter.class),
                new MouseEditAction());

Or use the DefaultEditBindings configuration.

Comment: Even with DefaultBindingConfiguration, Mouse selection is not working. Does the hierarchical order of configuration matter for editing as well?

Comment: yes, that is the default configuration behavior to make it possible to easy adjust the configuration